# Merge arrays in javascript

Tags: arrays

I have this array:

```
datas = [{USR_Website: "http://domain.com"}, {USR_FirstName: "Alex", USR_LastName: "Black", USR_Email: "ab@domain.com"}, {USR_Password: "fc6e6d7c3a72b46a69e2f8f594a775acef6b3ba1"}, {USR_Country: "CA", USR_TimeZone: "America/New_York"}];
```

How can I convert this array to have:

```
datas = {USR_Website: "http://domain.com", USR_FirstName: "Alex", USR_LastName: "Black", USR_Email: "ab@domain.com", USR_Password: "fc6e6d7c3a72b46a69e2f8f594a775acef6b3ba1", USR_Country: "CA", USR_TimeZone: "America/New_York"};
```

I want it like this because it more easy to make `datas.USR_Email` than
 `datas[1].USR_Email`.

Or perhaps, another solution ?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you already try something obvious like iterating over the array and adding elements as properties?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var target = {};
for (var i = 0, l = datas.length; i < l; i++) {
    for (var key in datas[i]) {
        target[key] = datas[i][key];
    }
}
```

You can now access the data as property of `target`, eg. `target.USR_Country`.